# Ubuntu SDK QML how to change the background color of TextField

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I have a situation where the background color of my QML app MainView causes the textfield entry to have grey lettering on equally dark brown background. This makes it almost impossible to read what text has been entered into the textfield.

When entering text it's fine because the background turns white and the dark text is now visible, but when a texfield isn't selected the text is unreadable.

Is there a way to change the background color of a textfield? I've already tried changing the text color, and it works when not entering text, but as soon as I click in the textfield to enter text I can't read it anymore because the textfield background color turns white and the text color is also very light.

Anyone have a solution to this issue they could suggest?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Ubuntu SDK comes with its own styled [TextField](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-1.0/Ubuntu.Components.TextField/) element. On dark background you can use the default Qt version by importing `QtQuick.Controls` (14.04 only). It will always render a white background but can also be styled with `TextFieldStyle`:

```js
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.1

MainView {
    width: 400
    height: 300
    backgroundColor: "black"

    Column {
        spacing: units.gu(2)
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        TextField {
            placeholderText: "ask"
        }
        TextField {
            placeholderText: "Enter text"
            text: "ubuntu"
            style: TextFieldStyle {
                textColor: "black"
                background: Rectangle {
                    radius: 5
                    color: "gold"
                    implicitWidth: 100
                    implicitHeight: 24
                    border.color: "#333"
                    border.width: 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It will look like the screenshot below:

[image]

Source: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-textfieldstyle.html

Comment: This is working perfectly for what I am trying to do, excellent idea. thanks.