# How can I create in QML a table of TextInput boxes with background

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, qml

How can I make a table with 6 rows 5 tables and 25 TextInput boxes, with background.

I've tried almost everything to put an background to the TextInput boxes, but still I could not get it right.

My code for the TextInput box is there:

```js
TextInput {
    y: 20;
    font.pixelSize: 10
    text: "Computador"
    cursorVisible: true;
    border.color: "#c0c0c0"
}
```

How can I make them and put a background color to them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a background with such elements, prefer the [TextField](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.04/Ubuntu.Components.TextField/) component instead (I suggested a similar usage in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/461734/32239)).

[image]

The corresponding code:

```js
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.1

MainView {
    id: main
    width: 400
    height: 300

    Column {
        spacing: units.gu(2)
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        TextInput {
            text: "default TextInput"
            cursorVisible: false
            width: main.width - units.gu(25)
        }
        TextField {
            placeholderText: "default TextField"
            width: main.width - units.gu(25)
        }
        TextField {
            placeholderText: "TextField with background"
            width: main.width - units.gu(25)
            text: "TextField with background"
            style: TextFieldStyle {
                textColor: "black"
                background: Rectangle {
                    radius: 5
                    color: "orange"
                    implicitWidth: 100
                    implicitHeight: 24
                    border.color: "#333"
                    border.width: 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sylvain thank you so much for all your help :).

Comment: Sylvain can you give me some opinion?? What should i use to make an app that needs to store int numbers, text-input or text-fields?? because i need 25 of them for an app that I'm building

Comment: You could store all of them in a QML var property, see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-var.html.

Comment: yes but i use text input so users can input the number what would you suggest, continue using them or use text-fields??

Comment: I'm not sure to understand correctly. Could you create a new question detailing your use case please?

Comment: ok i will do it

Comment: Sylvain here is the question. http://askubuntu.com/questions/492705/qml-what-to-use-to-store-int-numbers-textinput-or-textfield