# QML can't insert text into TextInput

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, qml

I have an TextInput box and I can't insert text into it, I have tried everything I knew but still I could not put text into it, or even delete a text I have put on it.

Here is some of the code I have:

```js
Rectangle {
    width: 40;
    height: 17;
    radius: 20.0
    id: q1
    x: 139
    y: 47
    color: "#F0EBEB"
    border.color: "#000000"

    TextInput {
        text: "0"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        cursorVisible: true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/492620/32239), prefer the [TextField](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-1.0/Ubuntu.Components.TextField/) component:

[image]

The corresponding code:

```js
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.1

MainView {
    id: main
    width: 200
    height: 200

    TextField {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        placeholderText: "0"
        text: "0"
        horizontalAlignment: TextInput.AlignHCenter
        style: TextFieldStyle {
            textColor: "black"
            background: Rectangle {
                radius: 20
                color: "#F0EBEB"
                implicitWidth: 40
                implicitHeight: 24
                border.color: "#000000"
                border.width: 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ty Sylvain, is there any link that you have so i can send you the final project??

Comment: Well for a single file http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/ is ok, for a full project, prefer a branch on https://launchpad.net/ or https://github.com/

Comment: here's the github link: https://github.com/diogof2014/ecolover3