# QML what to use to store int numbers TextInput or TextField

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

What is good to use on a Ubuntu Phone app that needs 25 variables to get input that are int numbers. Text fields or text input.

Right now I'm using text inputs to create the 25 ids that I'm going to use.

Here is an example of my code:

```js
   Rectangle {  width: 40; height: 17; radius: 20.0
                      id: rec2
                      x: 102
                      y: 50
                      color: "#F0EBEB"
                      border.color: "#000000"
                      // width, height
                      TextInput {
                          id: q2
                          text: "0"
                          anchors.centerIn: parent
                          cursorVisible: true
                      }
                  }
                   Rectangle {  width: 40; height: 17; radius: 20.0
                      id: rec3
                      x: 102
                      y: 67
                      color: "#F0EBEB"
                      border.color: "#000000"
                      // width, height
                      TextInput {
                          id: q3
                          text: "0"
                          anchors.centerIn: parent
                          cursorVisible: true
                      }
                  }
                   Rectangle {  width: 40; height: 17; radius: 20.0
                      id: rec4
                      x: 102
                      y: 84
                      color: "#F0EBEB"
                      border.color: "#000000"
                      // width, height
                      TextInput {
                          id: q4
                          text: "0"
                          anchors.centerIn: parent
                          cursorVisible: true
                      }
                  }
```

Comment: Do you want to restrict the field to only accept digits?

Comment: yes and then store them so i can use them later to make an calculation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are OK as they store the text property in a String.

You could use the following snippet to restrict the input (with [IntValidator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-intvalidator.html)) and make some calculation using the standard javascript function [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp):

```js
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.1

MainView {
    id: main
    width: 200
    height: 200

    TextField {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        placeholderText: "0"
        text: "12"
        validator: IntValidator{}
        horizontalAlignment: TextInput.AlignHCenter
        style: TextFieldStyle {
            textColor: "black"
            background: Rectangle {
                radius: 20
                color: "#F0EBEB"
                implicitWidth: 40
                implicitHeight: 24
                border.color: "#000000"
                border.width: 1
            }
        }
        onTextChanged: {console.log(parseInt(text,10) + 1000)}
    }
}
```

Comment: Sylvain so now do you thing i should delete all my TextInput boxes and change to TextField ??

Comment: I'd do that, especially if you also want to add a background to them